# How to get opcodes for assembly using ppc processor (IDAPython)

Tags: ida, assembly, idapython

In IDAPython, you can obtain the corresponding opcodes for a assembly instruction using the [Assemble(ea, line)](https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/python/idautils.py#651) function.

---

Here is an example using a PE-file / x86 processor type:

```
Python>Assemble(FirstSeg(), 'asdf')
Invalid mnemonic -> OK
(False, 'Assembler failed: asdf')
```

As we can see, the `Assemble` call returns `False` and prints a error message for a invalid mnemonic when using an incorrect assembly instruction like `asdf`.

With a valid assembly instruction, the correct opcode is returned:

```
Python>Assemble(FirstSeg(), 'ret')
(True, '\xc3')
```

---

Here is the same function using a PPC-ELF/ppc processor type:

```
Python>Assemble(FirstSeg(), 'asdf')
(True, '\x00')
```

As we can see, no error message is printed and a `\x00` is returned as resulting opcode.

The valid `sc` instruction and any other valid ppc instructions return the same (wrong) value of `\x00`:

```
Python>Assemble(FirstSeg(), 'sc')
(True, '\x00')
```

How can I get IDAPython's `Assemble(ea, line)` to return the proper opcodes when using a PPC-ELF/ppc processor type?

This is the trace the the function takes:

1. [Assemble(ea, line)](https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/python/idautils.py#651)
2. [_Assemble(ea, line)](https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/python/idautils.py#626)
3. [idaapi.AssembleLine(ea, cs, ip, use32, line)](https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/swig/idp.i#68)

And a usage example of Assemble(), if it wasn't clear:
https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/Scripts/FindInstructions.py

Comment: IDA doesn't support assembly for all architectures: "Currently, only the IBM PC processors provide an assembler" (from https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/529.shtml, though that is admittedly old). Are you sure PPC supports this?

Comment: @devttys0 Oh, this may actually be the reason. I just assumed that assembling would just work, as does disassembling. Is there a technical reason why it wouldn't? Isn't it just the reverse of disassembling, which IDA is already doing? The docs you linked say that `plugin writers can extend or totally replace the built-in assembler by writing their own`. Adding support for PPC this way would probably take alot of effort, wouldn't it?

Comment: It's up to the developer of the disassembler module to implement an assembler method. Most don't since that's more work and for something that's rarely used. I've written disassembler modules which are a bit of work, but I imagine just overriding the assembler method wouldn't be too much work (disclaimer: I've never done it).

Comment: That said, if you only need it for IDAPython, wrapping GNU's `as` (or radare2's `rasm2`) to and creating an equivalent `Assemble` function should not be that hard.